# Compiz or Unity not working

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, compiz, 14.10

After upgrading to the latest Nvidia Driver `340.58` the Ubuntu Desktop is not working. I get a blank screen with only my wallpaper.

This seems to be a common problem with lots of solutions, but after trying various things I still can't get my Unity/Compiz back to work.

My system:

- Ubuntu 14.10 64bit
- Nvidia GeForce 9600 GT
- Intel Core(TM)2 Quad Q6600

Output of `uname -a`

```
Linux [...] 3.16.0-26-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 1 19:19:18 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What I tried so far:

```
setsid compiz
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz
dpkg-reconfigure compiz
dconf reset -f /org/compiz
apt-get install ubuntu-desktop unity compiz --reinstall
```

The only thing that helps **until the next reboot** is:

```
rm -rf ~/.gconf ~/.gconfd ~/.metacity ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1 ~/.config/dconf
```

After executing this command Compiz crashes and restarts and works fine. Also the guest session works works without any problems.

I also tried the standard Nvidia drivers that ship with Ubuntu, without any success.

Maybe I am missing something out but I have no clue why Compiz or Unity keeps setting itself back to a faulty configuration file after I reboot the computer.

Answer (score 2):

What seemed to solve the problem for me was:

```
unity --reset
```

After this Unity configuration was set to its default values and everything works fine again.

Comment: is it --replace or --reset, please make sure, coz in man page --replace is not shown